# c# linq to list - 2 lists with same field names and results but only 1 works with json()?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

So I have `request1` and `request2` with same field names `Id` & `StartYear`

```
    public JsonResult GetFiscalYear(int? Level1Id, string filterText)
    {

        var request1 = (from FS in _db.FeeSchedules
                        join FIL in _db.FeeItemLines on FS.Id equals FIL.FeeScheduleId
                        join FY in _db.FiscalYears on FIL.FiscalYearId equals FY.Id
                        where FS.Level1Id == Level1Id
                        select new { FY.Id, FY.StartYear })
                          .OrderBy(o => o.StartYear)
                          .GroupBy(o => o.StartYear).ToList();

        var request2 = _db.FiscalYears.ToList();

        return Json(request1);
    }
```

For some reason, `request1` doesn't work and `request2` works, both have same field names, but it looks like `request1` list output doesn't work with the `Json()` function. But `request2` list works.

Side note, what's the name of the query in `request1` vs `request2`? I think they're both LINQ with Lambda?

**What I mean by it doesn't work:**

This drop down parses the `json` from `result2` but not `result1`

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("FiscalYearId")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:110px" })
          .OptionLabel("--Select--")
          .DataTextField("StartYear")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetFiscalYear", "Report")
               .Data("filterFiscalYear");
          }).ServerFiltering(true);
          })
          .Enable(false)
          .AutoBind(false)
          .CascadeFrom("Level1Id")
          .Value(sessionUser.CurrentFiscalYearId.ToString()
          )
    )
```

`request1` results in this:

[image]

`request2` results in this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Null output? Empty collection? Exception thrown?

Comment: i think because `request1` it's ``List<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`` and `request2` it's ``List<FiscalYear>``?try to use ``OrderBy`` and ``groupBy`` before ``select``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *Select* the *First* grouped result to match `request2` and to populate not duplicated `StartYear`, like the following code:

```
var request1 = (from FS in _db.FeeSchedules
                join FIL in _db.FeeItemLines on FS.Id equals FIL.FeeScheduleId
                join FY in _db.FiscalYears on FIL.FiscalYearId equals FY.Id
                where FS.Level1Id == Level1Id
                select new { FY.Id, FY.StartYear })
                  .OrderBy(o => o.StartYear)
                  .GroupBy(o => o.StartYear)
                  .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Beautiful! I think because the second select goes one level deeper for the json to parse.

Comment: I always feel like the `GroupBy(...).Select(x => x.First())` pattern is a bit fragile. It require more work if you refactor to `GroupBy(...).Select(x => x.Where(...).First())`. I much prefer the `GroupBy(...).SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))` pattern. It's much easier to add wheres or to do `Take(2)` etc.